# PHP string - what's wrong with '<'?

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I'm working with strings and somehow php just decides to ignore the following string if there is a "<" inside. I can't find anything about that. see this example:

```
$str = 'foo<bar'
// echoes foo, foo<bar expected
```

Are there any string operators I don't know about? Strings wrapped inside ' ' should not be evaluated by php, right?

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/310396)

Comment: could it be an issue with xampp 5.6.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
htmlspecialchars ("foo<bar");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your browser is probably interpreting it as HTML and it sees `<bar` as a partial HTML tag. Since it doesn't know how to render a `bar` tag it shows up as nothing and just the text `foo` is rendered.

If you go to `view-source` or send the file as `text/plain` all the text will show.

If you want to render the string `foo<bar` inside an HTML document you can do `echo htmlspecialchars($str)`, this will print the string as `foo&lt;bar`. This *escapes* the `<` character so it wont be interpreted as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Check the sourcecode view of the result page, the output is no valid html and thus invisible.

the right string is `'foo&lt;bar'`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your browser is deleting it because it looks like a bad html tag.

Press Ctrl+U (see source code) and check it out..